# how to get definition of identifier node typescript compiler

Tags: typescript

I am processing template strings

```
import {world} from "lib"
const text = `Hello ${world}`
```

I can get identifier node(world) from `templateSpans` , I want to get definition(filePath,...)  of `world` identifier node. typescript language service has `getDefinitionAtPosition(currentFileName,identifierNode.getStart())` , how can i achieve similar thing using compiler API ?

Comment: Sounds like you want `typeCheck.getSymbolAtLocation(identifierNode).declarations`

Comment: thanks alot , thats what i need :) , post as answer I'll accept.

Comment: Bruh. @Gerrit0what is typeCheck? Why didn't you post your answer as an answer?